# How to set a rule that assigns a user to a specific Organic Group after the checkout process

Tags: commerce, rules, organic-groups

I´m using rules, organic groups and drupal commerce modules.

I´ve set a rule that creates a new user after the anonymous completes the checkout process.

I want the rule to assign the user to a specific group (OG). I can´t find the way to do it.
I´ve added a screenshot of what are the available options,a nd it seems that there aren´t enough available selectors to do that.

Is there a way to add the user using php? How?
I´ve added the print screen after setting Action: Add entity to group.

[image: there aren´t enough data selectors]

Comment: What specific group is that? Does it have anything to do with the user or the shopping process?

Comment: Yes, the group is set as a referenced field inside the product that the user is buying.

Comment: But I could just add to the rule the subscription to an arbitrary group if I can do that with PHP...

Comment: So type "commerce-order:" in the group data collector. Does that give nothing?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this type of use case (selling access to an organic group) would be best handled now using the [Commerce License](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_license) framework, that has been designed specifically for this type of use cases.

We don't have integration with Organic Groups yet, but it seems straightforward to do in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is a step-by-step tutorial to do exactly what you want at http://s1l.org/selling-access-organic-groups-drupal-commerce

Also this would indeed be the perfect case for using the Commerce License framework.
There is [Commerce License OG module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_og) now.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. You can improve your answer by providing more details and leaving the link as a reference.